# Generating Valid Credit Card Track2 Data for Testing

Tags: testing, credit-card, load-testing

I have test cards from my payment processor but I do not have enough to do load testing , thus I need to generate card numbers and track data I can use through their test gateway.

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66880/how-to-test-credit-card-interactions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66880/how-to-test-credit-card-interactions)

Comment: It isn't a duplicate.  That post gives some card numbers that pass Luhn.  This questions is asking about card numbers AND track data for those cards.  The asker appears to be testing a card-present solution.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at [ISO 7813](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7813) for Track 1 & 2 generation.

Depending on your gateway, however, they may reject cards other than the test cards they've given you.  You might also want to warn them you're going to load test; I've had many card processors get very angry that we didn't tell them in advance that we were going to hammer their test system.

If you're load testing on a live system, prepare to pay big. =)  I once ran up quite a bit in fees ($10k?) by processing invalid authorizations.  (I was trying to find an extremely elusive bug only seen in production and needed an end-to-end test.  It turns out the bug was due to someone buying a cheaper alternative to a BigIP load balancer; so they saved up front but spent it anyway later.)